# Different width of frame across page bounadries with mdframed

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

When a `mdframed` frame begins with a display math, and the break occurs just at the end of the display math environment, the widths of the frame are different across the page break boundary:

[image]

Also note the inconsistent spacing on the first few lines of the second page.

### Notes:

- The page geometry changes were to allow for a better image to show the problem.
- I encounter this problem with Version `2012/04/08 v1.5`, but apparently the earlier version `2012/03/04 v1.4` works just fine.

### References:

- [mdframed : Bug with page break?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46873/mdframed-bug-with-page-break)
- [Inconsistent horizontal width of mdframed with only display math content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46588/inconsistent-horizontal-width-of-mdframed-with-only-display-math-content)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom=0.2cm,top=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[%
    leftmargin=0.5cm,
    rightmargin=0.5cm,
    backgroundcolor=yellow,%
    ]{Myframe}%

\begin{document}
\vspace*{24.75cm}
\begin{Myframe}
    \begin{align*}
        e &= mc^2\\
        F &= ma
    \end{align*}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{Myframe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please test the new version at github: https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today I uploaded the new version at github which fixed the problem. The idea was inspired by David Carlisle here: [Ignore first parskip inside a save box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56367/ignore-first-parskip-inside-a-save-box)

Also based on the new splitting algorithm the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom=0.2cm,top=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[%
    leftmargin=0.5cm,
    rightmargin=0.5cm,
    backgroundcolor=yellow,%
    ]{Myframe}%

\begin{document}
\vspace*{25.7cm}
\begin{Myframe}
    \begin{align*}
        e &= mc^2\\
        F &= ma
    \end{align*}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{Myframe}
\end{document}
```

results to:
[image]

Comment: Confirmed that this problem no longer occurs in the current version of TeXLive2012.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that a well-placed `\mbox{}` can sometimes help fix these types of bad breaks in an `mdframed` environment. Perhaps Marco Daniel will have a better fix though :)

[image]

```
\begin{Myframe}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{align*}
        e &= mc^2\\
        F &= ma
    \end{align*}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{Myframe}
```