# Ignore first parskip inside a save box

Tags: macros, environments, parskip

I have the following definition (MWE below) of a `lrbox`. If I use the normal setting `parskip=off` the interaction `\mdf@restoreparams` works as expected. Inside the `lrbox` I can use `parskip` and `parindent`. But if I use the option `parskip=half` I get an extra skip at the beginning of the save box. How can I avoid this.

**Picture**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\catcode`\@11\relax

\def\mdf@lrbox#1{%
 \edef\mdf@restoreparams{%
   \parindent=\the\parindent \parskip=\the\parskip}%
 \setbox#1\vbox\bgroup%
   \color@begingroup%
%     \mdf@horizontalmargin@equation%
     \columnwidth=\hsize%
     \textwidth=\hsize%
     \let\if@nobreak\iffalse%
     \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse%
     \let\par\@@par%
     \let\-\@dischyph%
     \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii%
     \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip%
     \linewidth\hsize%
     \@totalleftmargin\z@%
     \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip%
     \parfillskip\@flushglue \lineskip\normallineskip%
     \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip%
%%  \sloppy%
     \let\\\@normalcr%
     \hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize\relax
     \mdf@restoreparams\relax
     \@afterindentfalse%
     \@afterheading%
}

\def\endmdf@lrbox{\color@endgroup\egroup}


\newbox\MyTestBox

\begin{document}


\mdf@lrbox\MyTestBox
\kant[1]

\kant[1]
\endmdf@lrbox

\fbox{\box\MyTestBox}
\end{document}
```

I didn't tag this question with `KOMA` because the same result is reached by the header with a standard class

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{parskip}
```

or with `memoir`

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\nonzeroparskip
```

Comment: If you have any improvements I won't be disappointed ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well....

If you don't do

```
     \hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize\relax
```

Then you don't get the parskip at the top.

Then in your end code, if the width of the box is not what you expect (because no paragraph material has been added) do

```
\vbox{
hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize\relax
\unvbox the box you had
}
```

---

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\catcode`\@11\relax

\def\mdf@lrbox#1{%
 \edef\mdf@restoreparams{%
   \parindent=\the\parindent \parskip=\the\parskip}%
 \def\tmp{#1}%
 \setbox#1\vbox\bgroup%
   \color@begingroup%
%     \mdf@horizontalmargin@equation%
     \columnwidth=\hsize%
     \textwidth=\hsize%
     \let\if@nobreak\iffalse%
     \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse%
     \let\par\@@par%
     \let\-\@dischyph%
     \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii%
     \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip%
     \linewidth\hsize%
     \@totalleftmargin\z@%
     \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip%
     \parfillskip\@flushglue \lineskip\normallineskip%
     \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip%
%%  \sloppy%
     \let\\\@normalcr%
%     \hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize\relax
     \mdf@restoreparams\relax
     \@afterindentfalse%
     \@afterheading%

}

\def\endmdf@lrbox{\color@endgroup\egroup
\ifdim\wd\tmp<\hsize
\typeout{making box fill width}
\setbox\tmp\vbox{%
\hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize\relax
\unvbox\tmp}%
\fi
}


\newbox\MyTestBox

\begin{document}

\mdf@lrbox\MyTestBox
\kant[1]

\kant[1]
\endmdf@lrbox




\fbox{\box\MyTestBox}



\mdf@lrbox\MyTestBox
\begin{tabbing}aaa\end{tabbing}
\endmdf@lrbox


\fbox{\box\MyTestBox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The aim of the rule is to get the correct with of the `vbox` ;-) -- I tried `\setbox\MyTestBox=\vbox{\unvbox\MyTestBox}` but it didn't remains the first skip.

Comment: If a paragraph is started (ie you get the parskip) the box will have the correct width without that rule (as the paragraph lines will be hboxes of that width) you only need the rule when there is no paragraph, I'll fill out a patched MWE.

Comment: Exactly what I searched

Answer (score 2):

You can add `\vskip-\parskip` just at the end of the definition of `\mdf@lrbox`, that is between `\@afterheading` and the closing brace.

This will cancel out the `\parskip` glue automatically inserted when the first paragraph is about to be started.

Comment: So long as the paragraph _does_ get started. the reason why the rule is there in Marco's code is to catch the cases where no paragraph is started, to ensure the final box has full width.